# YUI Editor: How to paste as plain text?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yui, richtextbox, richtextediting

I implemented the Yahoo Rich Text Editor ([YUI Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)) in a Rails application using the [YUI_Editor Plugin](http://github.com/larsklevan/yui_editor/tree/master).

If I copy/paste text out of a PDF into a YUI-Editor-enhanced-TextArea (*YEETA* :)) it does not only copy the text but also the formatting of it.

How do I configure the YUI Editor to remove all formatting of text pasted into the *YEETA* before inserting it?

I'm intrested in your answer even if you're not working with Rails and/or using the YUI_Editor plugin. Give me a hint and I'll figure out how to solve this with my setup.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such function in the YUI editor. Finally I parsed the editor content on submit as described on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611843/yui-editor-getting-rid-of-html-tags-in-content).

Answer (score 2):

I've written an extension to the YUI editor to handle this, you can download it here:

http://antscode.blogspot.com/2009/05/strip-formatting-on-paste-using-yui.html

Comment: thanks a lot (though I switched to TinyMCE in the meantime ;-))!