# YUI Editor: Getting rid of <html> tags in content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yui, richtextbox, yui-editor

I implemented the [YUI rich text editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/) and I would like to get rid of the `<html>`, `<body>` and `DOCTYPE` tags as soon as I save the content from the editor. I know I could do this afterwards by parsing the HTML, but there must be a better solution.

Right now this is saved when I edit a text in the YUI editor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <p>foo</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

...but I would like to just save this:

```
<p>foo</p>
```

Any idea?

P.S.: I implemented the YUI editor using the [yui_editor plugin for ruby on rails](http://github.com/larsklevan/yui_editor/tree/master), but a YUI editor generic answer would be welcome too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I solved the problem myself by parsing the html on submit. Yes I know, I wasn't looking for this solution at first, but finally I came to the conclusion that it is the easiest way to solve it. I used the [Nokogiri RubyGem](http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/tree/master) for Rails to do the parsing:

```
value = Nokogiri::HTML(yui_content).css('body').to_html 
value.gsub!(/<body>/,'') 
value.gsub!(/<\/body>/,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be this, it uses regular expressions to catch everything between `<body`> and `</body>`. Example (modified from the YUI editor page):

```
var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('msgpost');
myEditor.render();

YAHOO.util.Event.on('somebutton', 'click', function() {
    myEditor.saveHTML();

    //The var html will now have the contents of the textarea
    var html = myEditor.get('element').value, match;

    match = html.match(/<body[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/body>/i);
    html = match ? match[1] : html;
});
```